# Standard Values TypeConverter error, but only when double clicking on the property value in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have placed a PropertyGrid in a Winforms application. One property is a standard values collection defined this way:

```
    [Category("Reloj Control")]
    [DisplayName("Entrada/Salida")]
    [Description("Indica el modo del lector (entrada o salida). Este valor sobrescribe el modo proveniente del lector.")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(AttendanceModeConverter))]
    [DefaultValue(-1)]
    public int Modo { get; set; }
```

AttendanceModeConverter is defined this way:

```
public class AttendanceModeConverter : System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
{
    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> _modos;

    static AttendanceModeConverter()
    {
        if (_modos == null)
        {
            _modos = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
            _modos.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,string>(-1, "Según reloj"));
            _modos.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,string>(0, "Entrada"));
            _modos.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Salida"));
        }
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return _modos != null;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return _modos != null;
    }

    public override System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return new StandardValuesCollection(_modos);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            if (value == null)
                return "Automático";

            if (value is KeyValuePair<int, string>)
                return ((KeyValuePair<int, string>)value).Value;

            return _modos.Where(m => m.Key.Equals((int)value)).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
            return _modos.Where(m => m.Value.Equals((string)value)).FirstOrDefault().Key;

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Almost all works perfectly. Drop down list displays the values to choose from, and I can change the property value. However, if I double click on the dropdown list, this error occurs:

**Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int32,System.String]' cannot be converted to 'System.Int32' type.**

Since this is shown by the property grid itself, I cannot debug further. I only suspect the problem is in ConvertTo function, but I cannot realize exactly what is the error and how to solve it.

Any advice will be appreciate, 
thanks

Comment: You are simply returning the wrong standard values.  Only an `int` can be stored in that property.  So `new StandardValuesCollection(new int[] {-1, 0, 1})` would be correct.

Comment: Yes... I know... but the return int should be the key of the dictionary. As I told, it works correcty when I choose the value from the drop down list, but when double clicking it does not. This is because when double clicking, value should change to the next value in the list. Can I use ConvertTo for that.

Comment: You need to change body of `GetStandardValues` method to this:

   `return new StandardValuesCollection(_modos.Select(x=>x.Key).ToList());`

Comment: You also can use enum as the type, or if enum is not suitable for you you can use just an enum converter, also if you those exact string representation, to see a clean implementation of the requirement take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39875777/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks..... it worked by changing GetStandardValues method the way you showed

Comment: Also don't miss the linked post for other available options, you may find the linked post useful :)